# Creative Testimonial Module

Tags: joomla2.5, testimonials

I am using Creative Testimonial module on Joomla 2.5 website but the sliding thing does not working. Today it stop working it has to work like this http://www.pluginvalley.com/demos/joomla-creative-testimonials-demo.html.

Answer (score 0):

If the module was properly written it should be working.  Have you changed the code on any of the pages within the module, or perhaps updated Joomla versions without updating the Testimonial module? Is the module version you installed documented a compatible with 2.5? Unfortunately we can't we-write a Joomla module on the fly for you.